# What is the better way of handling temporary strings?

Tags: cocoa, initialization, nsstring, release, allocation

I have a situation where I need to use some strings temporarily but I've read so many conflicting things that I'm a bit confused as to what the best way to proceed is.

I need to assign some strings inside an if structure but use them outside the if structure so they need to be created outside the if, I was thinking something like:

```
NSString *arbString = [[NSString alloc] init];

if(whatever)
{
    arbString = @"Whatever"
}
else
{
    arbString = @"SomethingElse"
}

myLabel.text = arbString;
[arbString release];
```

I have seen examples where people just used:

```
NSString *arbString;
```

to create the string variable

Google's Objective C guide says it's preferred to autorelease at creation time:

"When creating new temporary objects, autorelease them on the same line as you create them rather than a separate release later in the same method":

```
// AVOID (unless you have a compelling performance reason)
MyController* controller = [[MyController alloc] init];
// ... code here that might return ...
[controller release];

// BETTER
MyController* controller = [[[MyController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

So I have no idea, which is the best practice?

Comment: This answered my question, seems I was just phrasing it incorrectly.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706955/objective-c-if-statements-not-retaining/2706957#2706957

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you posted, you actually lose the reference to the NSString you created when you assign it in `arbString = @"Whatever"`. You then release the string constant (which is unreleasable, by the way).

So there's a memory leak, since you never release the NSString you created.

Remember that all these types are pointers, so `=` only reassigns them.

As for the question, in this example, you don't need the `[[NSString alloc] init]`. You don't need to copy the string into a local variable anyway, you can just set `myLabel.text` to the string constant `@"Whatever"`.

(edit: that's not to say that you can't use your pointer `arbString`, `arbString = @"Whatever"; myLabel.text = arbString` is fine. But this is just pointer assignment, not copying)

If you needed to manipulate the string before you returned it, you would create an NSMutableString, and either release or auto-release it. Personally, create autoreleased objects using class methods, so in this example, I'd use `[NSString string]`, or `[NSString stringWithString:]`, which return autoreleased objects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. You answered what I asked but it seems that I was phrasing the question incorrectly, problem was to do with scope & I was a bit off course.